# Laraver | Hide included element on master.blade.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How can I hide the sidebar on the home page (index.blade.php)?
Currently, I have something like this in master.blade.php:

```
  <main class="py-5">
        <div class="row" style="margin-right:15px;">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                @yield('content')
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-sx-12">
                @include('sidebar')
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

I need to display sidebar on all subpages except the home page (index.blade.php).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your index page is  the root `/` you can check like this:

```
@unless(request()->is('/'))
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-sx-12">
     @include('sidebar')
</div>
@endunless
```

---- EDIT

```
@if(request()->is('/'))
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    @yield('content')
</div>
@else
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     @yield('content')
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-sx-12">
     @include('sidebar')
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: That's it. But now on the index page I have an empty hole on the sidebar. I've used the bootstrap col-md-9 class before. What can I do to make the index col-md-12 only?

Comment: @Giacomo you can add both within the condition and then in the `@else` block put the content only with another div that spans in 12 blocks. Or just surround the `@include('sidebar')` with the `@unless` condition.

Comment: <3 Thanks @nakov

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a parameter from the index.blade.php file to the layout like: `@extends('layouts.master', ['noSideBar' => true])`. And then in your master.blade.php:

```
@unless(isset($noSideBar))
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-sx-12">
        @include('sidebar')
    </div>
@endunless
```

If you also want your other block to have a different class, your code would like this:

```
<main class="py-5">
    <div class="row" style="margin-right:15px;">
        <div class="{{ isset($noSideBar) ? 'col-md-12 : 'col-md-9' }} col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    @unless(isset($noSideBar))
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-sx-12">
            @include('sidebar')
        </div>
    @endunless
    </div>
</main>
```